# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'strEmail') How can I solve this problem?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm using Express.js writing this code to make a simple login post request :

```
app.post("/login", (req, res) => {
  res.send(
    {
    isUserRegistered: userLogin(req.body.strEmail, req.body.strPassword),
    }
  )
})

function userLogin(strEmail, strPassword) {
  if (strEmail.includes("mike@gmail.com") , strPassword.includes("12345")) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

My Body (raw):

```
{
    "strEmail":"mike@gmail.com",
    "strPassword":"12345"
}
```

And the expected response is `isUserRegistered:True` which depends on what i will pass in the body in postman, Any help?

Comment: Are you using body parser in Express? You probably aren't, which is why the body isn't parsed and is coming in as `undefined`. If you use Express 5, you can add before your routes `app.use(express.json())`, otherwise install [`body-parser`](https://npmjs.com/package/body-parser) and use `app.use(bodyParser.json())` (make sure to require `body-parser` first).

Comment: Also, you MUST validity check ALL parameters that come from a user BEFORE using them.  You cannot trust what's coming in from the user.  It could be empty, it could contain illegal characters, it could be junk.  Also, ,when you get an error like this why didn't you just insert a `console.log(req.body)` and see exactly what you have.  You shouldn't come here before executing the first step in debugging.

Comment: I'm glad you got it fixed. By the way, you might want to use `res.json({ ... })` instead of `res.send({ ... })`. I'm also not sure why you want to use `includes` instead of equality.

Comment: really I did all what you said and it runs properly, Most of this code is written by an instructor who used res.send and includes instead of == . but I modified it and it works . thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the scope here.

create a folder called `utils` and create a `userAuthentication.js` file there.
userAuthentication.js:

```
function userLogin(strEmail, strPassword) {
  if (strEmail === "mike@gmail.com" && strPassword === "12345") {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

module.exports = userLogin;
```

In your app.js or index.js file:

```
const express = require('express');
const userLogin = require('../utils/userAuthentication');
const app = express();
const port = 4000;

app.use(express.json());

app.post('/login', (req, res) =>{
  const { strEmail, strPassword } = req.body;
  const isAuthenticated = userLogin(strEmail, strPassword);
  if (isAuthenticated) {
    res.status(200).json({
      status: 'Ok',
      message: 'A user successfully logged in'
    });
  } else {
    res.status(500).json({
      status: 'Fail',
      message: 'Wrong credentials'
    }
});
```